# non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

tengo un problema al llamar a un metodo.

```
public class propietario{
public static void modificarCoeficiente (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BaseWeb base) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    ParticipantePOJO vParticipante = (ParticipantePOJO)session.getAttribute("Participante");
    String coef = request.getParameter("Coeficiente");
    double coeficiente = Double.parseDouble(coef);

    try{
        int IdParticipante = vParticipante.getIdParticipante();
        ModificarPreciosControlador ModificarPreciosControlador = new ModificarPreciosControlador();    
        ModificarPreciosControlador.modCoeficiente(IdParticipante, coeficiente);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        base.getLoggerGarageScanner().error("Se ha producido un error");
        request.setAttribute("errorpanelcontrol", "propietariocomunidaderrorcarga");
    }
    finally{

    }
}
}
```

Y estoy intentando llamar a este metodo.

```
public class ModificarPreciosControlador extends BaseControlador{

    public void modCoeficiente (int pIdParticipante, double coeficiente) throws Exception{
    ListaParametrosEntrada lstParametros = new ListaParametrosEntrada();
    lstParametros.addParametroEntrada(java.sql.Types.INTEGER, pIdParticipante);
    lstParametros.addParametroEntrada(java.sql.Types.INTEGER, coeficiente);

    super.lanzarProcedimientOut("spUpdateCoeficiente", lstParametros);

    //return null;
    }

}
```

Pero me da el error siguiente:

> ```
> non static method cannot be referenced from a static context java.
> ```

Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear una instancia de ModificarPreciosControlador para poder acceder a sus métodos no estáticos.

Así, en tu código, en vez de hacer

```
ModificarPreciosControlador.modCoeficiente(IdPropietario, IdComunidad, coeficiente);
```

deberías hacer:

```
ModificarPreciosControlador controlador = new ModificarPreciosControlador();    
controlador.modCoeficiente(IdPropietario, IdComunidad, coeficiente);
```

---

Si lo que quieres es mantener todos los métodos como estáticos, la manera más sencilla de hacerlo es cambiar de

```
 public void modCoeficiente (int pIdParticipante, double coeficiente) throws Exception
```

a

```
public static void modCoeficiente (int pIdParticipante, double coeficiente) throws Exception
```

Y en `modificarCoeficiente` llamar al método de manera estática:

```
ModificarPreciosControlador.modCoeficiente(IdParticipante, coeficiente);
```

***********solucion*************

```
ModificarPreciosControlador modContr = new ModificarPreciosControlador(base.getVariablesGlobales());// incluir esta linea de codigo en metodo modificarCoeficiente

modContr.modCoeficiente(IdParticipante, coeficiente);// y cambiar esta llamada al otro metodo por la antigua.



public  void modCoeficiente (int pIdParticipante, double coeficiente) throws Exception{}//Cambiar el tipo del metodo
```

Y ya esta, muchas gracias

Comment: Tras hacer unas pruebas, me sigue sin funcionar, no llega al metodo ModificarPreciosControlador.modCoeficiente(IdPropietario, IdComunidad, coeficiente); He hecho un Debug paso a paso, y no llega a entrar al meotod :S

Comment: Tienes que aplicar la misma lógica, crear una instancia y a través de ella llamar al método.

Comment: Eso he hecho, crear la instancia y llamarla, pero no entra :S

Comment: Copia el código actualizado en la pregunta

Comment: ya esta editado el codigo

Comment: Has llamado a tu variable igual que el nombre de la clase, empezando por mayúscula, por lo que no la está usando. Pon el nombre de la variable en minúscula. Nunca pongas nombres en mayúscula a las instancias de clases, es una mala práctica.

Comment: ModificarPreciosControlador controlador = new ModificarPreciosControlador();    
            controlador.modCoeficiente(IdParticipante, coeficiente);                       Asi imagino? pero me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿El mismo error? Pon la traza

Comment: Vale, no había visto que tu método modificarCoeficiente es estático también. ¿Es realmente necesario?

Comment: Por otro lado, tu clase propietario empieza por minúscula, esto es otra mala práctica, renómbrala a Propietario.

Comment: La clase esta en mayuscula, lo que pasa que eso lo escribí a mano, y se me colo la mayuscula :S

Comment: Bueno, pues piensa si es necesario que el método modificarCoeficiente sea estático y, en base a eso, la solución será una u otra.

Comment: Los demas metodos de ese estilo del proyecto son estaticos, pero si lo pongo static, me da el error que comento en el titulo

Comment: Actualizo mi respuesta

Comment: Me sigue sin dejar,el error me lo sigue dando, pero ahora en la llamada al metodo super.lanzarProcedimientOut("spUpdateCoeficiente", lstParametros);. El metodod lanzarProcedimientoOut, es un metodo public

Comment: El método lanzarProcedimientOut también debe ser estático. Tienes que plantearte si estás haciendo bien dejando todo estático, al fin y al cabo esto es programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: Vale, ya solucione el problema, muchas gracias, en la pregunta pongo la solucion, gracias de nuevo, un saludo :)