# ¿Como consumir metodos generados por Web Service Client?

Tags: java, webservice

he creado este metodo del WebService

Service.java

```
package Servicios;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "Service")
public class Service {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

Ademas he creado un webServiceClient para consumirlo

y tengo este index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="jsp/actionLogin.jsp" method="post"> 
            <input value="Hello" name="Hello"/>
            <input value="Luisa" name="Luisa"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Al agregar un Web Service Cliente me genero estas clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo un JSP donde trato de consumir el metodo del WebService de las clases generadas

en este caso seria este metodo que quiero consumir:

```
package servicios;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.10-b140803.1500
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "Service", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface Service {


    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.String
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "hello", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/", className = "servicios.Hello")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "helloResponse", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/", className = "servicios.HelloResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://Servicios/Service/helloRequest", output = "http://Servicios/Service/helloResponse")
    public String hello(
        @WebParam(name = "name", targetNamespace = "")
        String name);

}
```

Pero en mi JSP no logro ver ese metodo

```
<%@page import="servicios.HelloResponse"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String value = request.getParameter("Hello");
            String value2 = request.getParameter("Luisa");

            servicios.Service.hello(value);

            %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pero me marca error, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

el error es:

**non-static method hello(String) cannot be referenced from a static context**

Edicion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edicion:

Agregue la interface

```
package servicios;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.10-b140803.1500
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "ServicioWeb", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface ServicioWeb {


    /**
     * 

     * @return
     *     returns boolean
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Hello")
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "Hello", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/", className = "servicios.Hello")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "HelloResponse", targetNamespace = "http://Servicios/", className = "servicios.HelloResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://Servicios/ServicioWeb/HelloRequest", output = "http://Servicios/ServicioWeb/HelloResponse")
    public boolean hello(
        @WebParam(name = "user", targetNamespace = "")
        String user);

}
```

Comment: El error de compilación se debe porque el método estático esta accediendo a un atributo no estático (que forma parte del objeto creado) y por ende, necesita una referencia a ese objeto para poder acceder a dicho atributo, de lo contrario, habrá error.

Comment: Hola @MrDave1999 pero yo no declare nada estatico, y el codigo que me genera, genera una interface. Por ende no puedo hacer new objeto. Que cambio debería de hacer?

Comment: ¿En que linea el compilador da el error?

Comment: En el jsp donde intento consumir el metodo de las clases generadas `servicios.Service.hello(value);`

Comment: Tu pregunta está duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59944/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context . El código debería ser: `servicios.hello(value);`.

Comment: No le llego aun, adjunte una imagen con el error.

Comment: Escribí una respuesta, espero te sirva. Eh, por cierto, no puedes tener un mismo nombre para una clase e interfaz, de lo contrario, dará error de compilación.

Comment: agregue la interface @MrDave1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginemos que tenemos la siguiente clase:

```java
class Service 
{
    public String hello(String txt)
    {
        return "hello " + txt;
    }
}
```

Y posteriormente usamos la clase de esta manera:

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Service.hello("Luisa");
    }
}
```

Esta línea de código:

```java
Service.hello("Luisa");
```

Nos dará un error de compilación, debido a que, el método `hello` no es estático. El nombre de la clase `Service` solo se lo puede usar para **acceder a métodos o atributos ESTÁTICOS**.

Si editamos la definición del método `hello` y lo hacemos estático:

```java
class Service 
{
    public static String hello(String txt)
    {
        return " hello" + txt;
    }
}
```

Sería válido usarlo de esta manera:

```java
Service.hello("Luisa");
```

Por lo tanto, no habrá error de compilación porque `hello` es un método estático.

Ahora para acceder a un método de instancia es obligatorio instanciar la clase, de lo contrario, no habrá forma de acceder a los miembros (métodos y atributos) de la clase `Service`.

```java
class Service 
{
    public String hello(String txt)
    {
        return " hello" + txt;
    }
}

public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        //Creamos el objeto..
        Service servicios = new Service();
        //Accedemos al método hello  
        servicios.hello("Luisa");
    }
}
```

Este mismo error pasaría si llegáramos a usar una interfaz:

```java
interface Service 
{
    String hello(String txt);
}

class ServiceWeb implements Service
{
    @Override
    public String hello(String txt)
    {
        return "Hello "+ txt;
    }
}


public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Service.hello("Luisa");//error de compilación.
    }
}
```

El error se debe porque `hello` no es un método estático y aunque le agreguemos el `static` a la declaración del método `hello` de la interfaz `Service`, el error: `non-static method hello(String) cannot be referenced from a static context` se solucionará, sin embargo, aparecerá otro error, debido a que, la rutina `hello` no tendría una implementación (un cuerpo de código).

La solución a dicho error es crear un objeto de tipo `ServiceWeb` y posteriormente, invocar el método `hello` a través de la variable `servicio` (de tipo `Service`).

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Service servicio = new ServiceWeb();
        servicio.hello("Luisa");
    }
}
```

Para que este código compile correctamente, la clase `ServiceWeb` si o si, deberá implementar el método `hello` de la interfaz `Service`.

Comment: Entiendo bien, pero tengo una consulta. Digamos si Service es una interface que ocurre?

Comment: @Luisa Actualicé mi respuesta, espero te sirva!